# Loading model state into FaceRecognizer from memory or string in python opencv

Tags: python, opencv, amazon-s3, lbph-algorithm

Is it possible to load the model for a FaceRecognizer from memory or a string rather than from a saved file.  The API docs do not show a 'FromString or Buffer' version.

The current code loads from file:

```
model = cv2.createLBPHFaceRecognizer()
model.load('model.xml')
```

Some more background.  The presisted models are stored in S3.  I don't want to retrieve from S3 and then save to disk in order to use.  I would rather load directly from s3 into the model or load the xml string/document into the model.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

unfortunately, not possible from python ( cv2 ) atm.

while you *can* do it from c++ ,

```
string yml; // the whole schlepp in a string
FileStorage fs;
fs.open(yml,FileStorage::READ|FileStorage::MEMORY);
facereco->load(fs);
fs.release();
```

sad as it is, you can neither access FileStorage api, nor the FaceReco::load(FileStorage&) methods from python

(sidenote : at least you could resave them once from the facereco as yml.gz, to get the traffic down to 1/5 of the uncompressed xml)

Comment: Thanks for the info.  Too bad I can't do it from python yet - this would be a nice feature to add to cv2.   Will also look into using yml.

Comment: yea, i know, been playing around with heroku and such myself, where ther's no treal filesystem, or only an ephemeral one.